# Is there a way to share fixtures while using cy.fixture in class between methods

Tags: javascript, oop, cypress

I am doing my first steps in Cypress and issue which I meet is that I replicate the code so I wish to make it better. I've tried to use cy.fixture in a constructor but it failed, so I am looking for a way to use cy.fixture only once in class and assign result to this which can be used in other methods.

```
class LoginPage{

navigate(){
    cy.fixture('urls.json').then((url) => {
        cy.visit(url.baseUrl);
    })
}

checkIfRedirected(){
    cy.reload()
    cy.fixture('urls.json').then((url) => {
        cy.url().should('equal', url.claimUrl)
    })
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to import the fixture at the top of the LoginPage

```js
import url from './cypress/fixture/urls.json'

class LoginPage {

  navigate() {
    cy.visit(url.baseUrl);
  }

  checkIfRedirected(){
    cy.reload()
    cy.url().should('equal', url.claimUrl)
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to add, this has to be done in non-spec files

Comment: Spec files are JS also, you can import your fixtures there also.